# Ruby, XOR random bytes in binary string

Tags: ruby, byte, xor

I have a string of binary data and want to pick a single character, and ^ it by 0xff. Is there a simple way to do this?  For example:

```
x = "test\223\434t"
r = rand(x.length)
c = x[r].unpack("H*") ^ 0xff # This doesnt work
# Re concat the string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bytes = x.bytes.to_a
# => [116, 101, 115, 116, 147, 28, 116]
bytes[rand(bytes.length)] ^ 0xff
# => 139
```

Comment: is there an easy way to inject that char into the string?

Comment: r=rand(bytes.length); bytes[r] = bytes[r] ^ 0xff; s = bytes.pack("a*");